# recipe for target 'sysdata' failed - negative length vectors are not allowed (compilation R-cran v4.0.0)

Tags: r, makefile, compilation

I am trying to build `R-cran` `v4.0.0` using the following flags:

```
CFLAGS="-Ofast -march=native -pipe -mtune=native" CXXFLAGS="${CFLAGS}" ./configure --with-cairo --with-x --with-libpng --with-jpeglib --with-libtiff --enable-R-shlib --enable-BLAS-shlib --enable-memory-profiling --with-readline --with-tcltk  -with-blas="-lf77blas -latlas"
```

During the make I get a very strange error:

```
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/quics/src/R-4.0.0/src/library/tools/src'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/quics/src/R-4.0.0/src/library/tools/src'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/quics/src/R-4.0.0/src/library/tools'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/quics/src/R-4.0.0/src/library/tools'
installing 'sysdata.rda'
Error in unique.matrix(S3methods[seq_len(nS3), , drop = FALSE]) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
Calls: ::: ... loadNamespace -> parseNamespaceFile -> unique -> unique.matrix
Execution halted
../../../share/make/basepkg.mk:150: recipe for target 'sysdata' failed
make[4]: *** [sysdata] Error 1
```

I have search on the internet but havent seen nothing serious concerning a problem.

Any tips on how to debug, or why/what could be returning a negative length vectors ???

Comment: For Ubuntu I have a Dockerfile that compiles R 4.0.0: https://github.com/robertdj/r-dockerfiles/blob/R4/r-minimal/Dockerfile

Comment: I am trying to make a Dockerfile with an ATLAS build

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is caused the usage of `-Ofast` as compilation flag. Replacing it with `-O3` solved the problem.

Maybe `seq_len(nS3)` returned a negative number instead of the correct length ??